How do I make 2 Immovable Objects Collide and Just Stop
I have searched online for many hours for an answer, but no one seemed to be doing movement like I was. I just started my Phaser journey, and got stuck pretty early. I want my game to have movement locked onto the player in the center, with everything else moving around it. When I tried to add a building, however, the player would be pushed out from the middle.
I have tried setting both sprites to immovable or .body.moves = false, but that just ends up making the 2 sprites phase through each other. I have also tried locking the player to the center, with no luck. If there is a better way to go about player movement, let me know, but for now I cannot figure this out.
CODE:
class greenearth extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("startGame");
    }
    create() {
        this.playerCanMove = true;
        this.keyA = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
        this.keyS = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
        this.keyD = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
        this.keyW = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
        this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, config.width, config.height, "background").setScale(2);
        this.background.setOrigin(0, 0);
        this.house = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 300, "house").setScale(1);
        this.house.setImmovable(true);
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, "player").setScale(4);
        this.player.play("idle");
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.house);

    }
    playerMovement(delta) {
        this.playerStopped();
        if (this.keyA.isDown) {
            this.playerMovedLeft(player.speed, delta);
        } else if (this.keyD.isDown) {
            this.playerMovedRight(player.speed, delta);
        }
        if (this.keyW.isDown) {
            this.playerMovedUp(player.speed, delta);
        } else if (this.keyS.isDown) {
            this.playerMovedDown(player.speed, delta);
        }

        this.player.body.velocity.normalize().scale(player.speed);
        if (this.keyA.isDown) {
            this.player.play("walkLeft", true);
        } else if (this.keyD.isDown) {
            this.player.play("walkRight", true);
        } else if (this.keyW.isDown) {
            this.player.play("walkUp", true);
        } else if (this.keyS.isDown) {
            this.player.play("walkDown", true);
        } else {
            this.player.play("idle", true);
        }
    }

    playerMovedLeft(speed, delta) {
        let speedCorrection = (1000 / 60) / delta;
        this.house.setVelocityX(player.speed * speedCorrection);
        this.background.tilePositionX -= this.house.body.velocity.x / 120;

    }
    playerMovedRight(speed, delta) {
        let speedCorrection = (1000 / 60) / delta;
        this.house.setVelocityX(-player.speed * speedCorrection);
        this.background.tilePositionX -= this.house.body.velocity.x / 120;
    }
    playerMovedUp(speed, delta) {
        let speedCorrection = (1000 / 60) / delta;
        this.house.setVelocityY(player.speed * speedCorrection);
        this.background.tilePositionY -= this.house.body.velocity.y / 120;
    }
    playerMovedDown(speed, delta) {
        let speedCorrection = (1000 / 60) / delta;
        this.house.setVelocityY(-player.speed * speedCorrection);
        this.background.tilePositionY -= this.house.body.velocity.y / 120;
    }
    playerStopped() {
        this.house.setVelocityX(0);
        this.house.setVelocityY(0);
    }
    update(time, delta) {
        this.playerMovement(delta);
        // this.player.x = config.width/2;
        // this.player.y = config.height/2;
    }
}


The easy solution is to set the camera to follow the player, with the function startFollow.
(link to the documentation)
Here Short Demo, showcasing this:


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: { create },
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Camera set to follow the player')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 10, 10);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    graphics.generateTexture('obj', 20, 20);
    
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    this.player = this.physics.add.image(150, 90, 'img');
    this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.player.setImmovable(true)
    
    let testHouse = this.physics.add.image(200, 90, 'obj');
    testHouse.setVelocity(-150, 0);
    
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, testHouse);
    
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);

}

new Phaser.Game(config);

console.clear();
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




ACTUAL GODSEND! I can’t believe I spent so many hours hard coding a camera follow function when it already exists. I am mad and happy. Thank you so much. Is there anyway to find out everything about phaser? I watched hours of tutorials and never came across this. There is probably so much more that I could be saving time on. Thanks again!

Well my first tipp would be to checkout the offical phaser examples, if you have some time click through some of them, or if you are looking for something specific just use the search. Most features and functions are shown here (I never stop being amazed, what I can find there).  But also the official documentation, can help and an unofficial HowTo collection might help. I hope this makes your journey a bit easier.

btw.: A free official ebook came out a while ago, but I don't know how good it is.  P.s.: You can also checkout the phaser discourse and/or discord, there you can sometimes even interact with the Phaser Dev's. :)
